# Trying to use the certificate to connect in a web server

Tags: java, web-services, certificate, tomcat8, x509certificate2

I ve been trying to use two different certificates to communicate in a web server( Web server 1). When I use the first one, I can communicate with the web server without any problem. But when I try to use the second one, I have some problems: Even if I change the certificate and make another conection with the web server, it returns the information that a had  used in the first certificate.
When I close and open the tomcat 8, I can use the second one, but I can't use the first one again.
I´ve been using more than one certificate , and using the same method in another web server(Web server 2) without problem.

Follow the code bellow:

```
 public String sendXml(String xmlCabecalho, String xmlEnvNFse) throws ExceptionServicoAbrasf {
    try {
        SignXml signXml = new SignXml(this.keyStoreService.getKeystore(), this.keyStoreService.getAliasCert(), this.keyStoreService.getPasswordPfx());
        xmlEnvNFse = signXml.signAndSend(xmlEnvNFse);
        loadInfoCertificate();
        return executarServicoEnvioNFse(xmlCabecalho, xmlEnvNFse);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new ExceptionServicoAbrasf("Failure to sing. " + ex.getMessage());
    }

}
//add xml to sign
  public String signAndSend(String xml) throws Exception {
      //sign
    return sign(xml, "InfDeclaracaoPrestacaoServico", "Rps");
}
```

//sign

```
   private String sign(String xml, String tag, String tagParentSignature) throws Exception {
    Document document = documentFactory(xml);

    XMLSignatureFactory signatureFactory = XMLSignatureFactory
            .getInstance("DOM");
    ArrayList<Transform> transformList = signatureFactory(signatureFactory);
    loadCertificates(signatureFactory);

    NodeList elements = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    org.w3c.dom.Element el = (org.w3c.dom.Element) elements.item(0);
    el.setIdAttribute("Id", true);
    String id = el.getAttribute("Id");

    Reference ref = signatureFactory.newReference("#" + id,
            signatureFactory.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA1, null),
            transformList, null, null);

    SignedInfo si = signatureFactory.newSignedInfo(signatureFactory
            .newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE,
                    (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null), signatureFactory
            .newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA1, null),
            Collections.singletonList(ref));

    XMLSignature signature = signatureFactory.newXMLSignature(si, keyInfo);

    DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(privateKey, document.getElementsByTagName(tagParentSignature).item(0));
    signature.sign(dsc);

    return outputXML(document);
}  
//load certificate
 protected void loadCertificates(XMLSignatureFactory signatureFactory) throws Exception {
    if (keyStore != null) {
        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry = null;
        if (keyStore.isKeyEntry(alias)) {
            char[] pin = (password == null ? "" : password).toCharArray();
            pkEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias,
                    new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(pin));
            privateKey = pkEntry.getPrivateKey();
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) pkEntry.getCertificate();

            KeyInfoFactory keyInfoFactory = signatureFactory.getKeyInfoFactory();
            List<X509Certificate> x509Content = new ArrayList<>();

            x509Content.add(cert);
            X509Data x509Data = keyInfoFactory.newX509Data(x509Content);
            keyInfo = keyInfoFactory.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(x509Data));
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Alias invalid.");
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Invalid Certificate Information.");
    }
}
///normalize xml
 protected String outputXML(Document doc) throws TransformerException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
    trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(os));
    String xml = os.toString();
    if ((xml != null) && (!"".equals(xml))) {
        xml = xml.replaceAll("\\r\\n", "");
        xml = xml.replaceAll(" standalone=\"no\"", "");
    }
    return xml;
}
//load info certificate
     private void loadInfoCertificate() {
    System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");
    Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");

    System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore");
    System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword");
    System.clearProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", this.keyStoreService.getPathPfx());
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", this.keyStoreService.getPasswordPfx());

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", this.pathCacerts);

}
//send web service
    private String executarServicoEnvioNFse(String xmlCabecalho, String xmlCorpo) throws ExceptionServicoAbrasf {
    Input input = new Input(xmlCabecalho, xmlCorpo);
    Output output = generateReturn(input);
    return output.getOutputXML();

}
//generate conection web service
    private Output generateReturn(ws.Input parameters) throws ExceptionServicoAbrasf {
    ws.Nfse port = loadNfseDivPort();
    return port.generateReturn(parameters);
}
//return web service
    private ws.Nfse loadNfseDivPort() throws ExceptionServicoAbrasf {
    try {
        String urlStr = "https://homolog.govdigital.com.br/ws/div?wsdl";
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        ws.NfseServiceImplDivService service = new ws.NfseServiceImplDivService(url);
        ws.Nfse port = service.getNfseDivPort();
        return port;
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        throw new ExceptionServicoAbrasf("Invalid url. " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, non-English identifier names. Cute, but hard to read. Also, the question is missing a [mcve].

Comment: I have a problem because I can´t send my Certificate to you reproduce the code for security reasons.